# How to return Nested TreeView JSON in Web API

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to `web API`. I need some help to generate the `JSON` like following.

```
 [
    {
        'id': 66,
        'text': 'This is the first comment.',
        'creator': {
            'id': 52,
            'display_name': 'Ben'
        },
        'respondsto': null,
        'created_at': '2014-08-14T13:19:59.751Z',
        'responses': [
            {
                'id': 71,
                'text': 'This is a response to the first comment.',
                'creator': {
                    'id': 14,
                    'display_name': 'Daniel',
                },
                'respondsto': 66,
                'created_at': '2014-08-14T13:27:13.915Z',
                'responses': [
                    {
                        'id': 87,
                        'text': 'This is a response to the response.',
                        'creator': {
                            'id': 52,
                            'display_name': 'Ben',
                        },
                        'respondsto': 71,
                        'created_at': '2014-08-14T13:27:38.046Z',
                        'responses': []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'id': 70,
        'text': 'Đây là bình luận thứ hai.',
        'creator': {
            'id': 12,
            'display_name': 'Nguyễn'
        },
        'respondsto': null,
        'created_at': '2014-08-14T13:25:47.933Z',
        'responses': []
    }
];
```

My Intention is to give JSON Data for the  [Image](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ECmAa8QLg5s/V5jhmJDUiZI/AAAAAAAACco/a6zOwGBUXkQBrQf-pkZC98oV9EWzUfx0gCLcB/s1600/Facebook%2BComment%2Bsection.jpg).

I'm able to generate normal [JSON](https://api.myjson.com/bins/18knqy) data. I was struck how to create that responses inside responses until the empty response comes.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I found the [Answer](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yYyZ1m)

Comment: Can you show us the 'normal json data'?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I updated normal JSON Data @SangramNandkhile. I can loop for single time inside response. But, unable to loop if the value is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                
public class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
    var source = new List<TreeModel>
    {
        new TreeModel
        {
            ChangeFlowsFromParent = false,
            ChangeFlowsToParent = true,
            StreamType = "mainine",
            StreamName = "ArgOS_2_0",
            Parent = null,
            Compliance = "Released",
        },
        new TreeModel
        {
            ChangeFlowsFromParent = true,
            ChangeFlowsToParent = true,
            StreamType = "Release",
            StreamName = "ArgOS_2_0_DHAL1",
            Parent = "ArgOS_2_0",
            Compliance = "Released",
        },
        new TreeModel
        {
            ChangeFlowsFromParent = false,
            ChangeFlowsToParent = true,
            StreamType = "Release",
            StreamName = "ArgOS_2_0_child_DHAL2",
            Parent = "ArgOS_2_0_DHAL1",
            Compliance = "Released",
        },
        new TreeModel
        {
            ChangeFlowsFromParent = false,
            ChangeFlowsToParent = true,
            StreamType = "Release",
            StreamName = "ArgOS_child_Gen2",
            Parent = "ArgOS_2_0_child_DHAL2",
            Compliance = "Released",
        },
        new TreeModel
        {
            ChangeFlowsFromParent = true,
            ChangeFlowsToParent = true,
            StreamType = "Release",
            StreamName = "ArgOS_2_0_DHAL2",
            Parent = "ArgOS_2_0",
            Compliance = "Released",
        },
        new TreeModel
        {
            ChangeFlowsFromParent = true,
            ChangeFlowsToParent = true,
            StreamType = "Release",
            StreamName = "ArgOS_2_0_DHAL3",
            Parent = "ArgOS_2_0",
            Compliance = "Released",
        },
    };
    var output = MapToTreeModelJsonCollection(source);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(output,Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}

static ICollection<TreeModelJson> MapToTreeModelJsonCollection(ICollection<TreeModel> source)
{
    // map all items
    var allItems = source.Select(e => new TreeModelJson
                                 {
                                     ChangeFlowsFromParent = e.ChangeFlowsFromParent.ToString().ToLower(),
                                     ChangeFlowsToParent = e.ChangeFlowsToParent.ToString().ToLower(),
                                     Compliance = e.Compliance,
                                     Parent = e.Parent ?? "none",
                                     StreamName = e.StreamName,
                                     StreamType = e.StreamType,
                                 }).ToList();
    
    // build tree structure
    foreach (var item in allItems)
    {
        var children = allItems.Where(e => e.Parent == item.StreamName).ToList();
        if (children.Any())
        {
            item.Children = children;
        }
    }
    
    // return only root items
    return allItems.Where(e => e.Parent == "none").ToList();
}


class TreeModel
{
    public string StreamName { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public string StreamType { get; set; }
    public bool ChangeFlowsFromParent { get; set; }
    public bool ChangeFlowsToParent { get; set; }
    public string Compliance { get; set; }
    public string Parent { get; set; }
}

class TreeModelJson
{
    [JsonProperty("ChangeFlowsFromParent")]
    public string ChangeFlowsFromParent { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ChangeFlowsToParent")]
    public string ChangeFlowsToParent { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("StreamType")]
    public string StreamType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("streamName")]
    public string StreamName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Parent")]
    public string Parent { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Compliance")]
    public string Compliance { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("children", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public ICollection<TreeModelJson> Children { get; set; }
}

}
```

This would generate expected JSON fromat